# How do I order a many to many relationship based on a field in the intermediary table?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am writing a django application that tracks ranked statistics for a player in a video game.

When I define the "through" field of a many to many relationship, I expect the resulting query to be ordered using the "ordering" meta field of the intermediary object.

I cannot get the test below to pass. My db is fully migrated. Where am I misunderstanding things?

Model Code

```
from django.db import models

class Player(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class GameMode(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    leaderboard = models.ManyToManyField(Player, through="ELO", related_name="game_modes")

class ELO(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name="elos", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    game_mode = models.ForeignKey(GameMode, related_name="elos", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    current = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    peak = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["player", "game_mode"]
        ordering = ("-current",)
```

Test Code

```
def test_leaderboard_works_okay_with_different_game_modes(db):
    # checks that creating player elos will have them sorted on the game_mode leaderboard
    game_mode1 = GameMode.objects.create()
    game_mode2 = GameMode.objects.create()
    player1 = Player.objects.create()
    player2 = Player.objects.create()

    ELO.objects.create(game_mode=game_mode1, player=player1, current=1500)
    ELO.objects.create(game_mode=game_mode2, player=player1, current=1000)

    ELO.objects.create(game_mode=game_mode1, player=player2, current=1000)
    ELO.objects.create(game_mode=game_mode2, player=player2, current=1500)

    assert game_mode1.leaderboard.first() == player1
    assert game_mode2.leaderboard.first() == player2
```

Error Log

The leaderboard has the list of players, but they aren't correctly ordered and the assertion fails.

```
>       assert game_mode2.leaderboard.first() == player2
assert <Player: Player object (30a9670a-28de-4027-b7c0-70cec65ec08e)> == <Player: Player object (829acf41-03fd-45ef-b1eb-3b3f7c7170a0)>
E        +  where <Player: Player object (30a9670a-28de-4027-b7c0-70cec65ec08e)> = <bound method QuerySet.first of <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x7f63abb5b890>>()
E        +    where <bound method QuerySet.first of <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x7f63abb5b890>> = <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x7f63abb5b890>.first
E        +      where <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x7f63abb5b890> = <GameMode: GameMode object (58)>.leaderboard
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution. It's better to call the player property what it is (a group of players) and define a leaderboard property that orders them. I can get the current ELO in context using the related name "elos__current".

Making this change passed my test.

```
class GameMode(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    players = models.ManyToManyField("players.Player", through="ELO", related_name="game_modes")

    @property
    def leaderboard(self):
        return self.players.order_by("-elos__current")
```